# Image uploader and manager

Tags: beginner, ruby, image

I have recently started using Ruby and would like to hear your take on the following piece of code.

```
class Generator

  def initialize
    @context = nil
  end

  def start(params)
    @context = Context.new params
    image = create_image
    if cache_update_request?
      upload image
    end
    return image
  end

  def create_image
    composer = Composer.new @context
    execution_context = ExecutionContext.new(@context, composer)
    execution_context.render
  end

  def upload(image)
    uploader = CompositorCommons::CacheUpdater.new
    filename = @context.parameters[:cache]
    location = 'dual/' + filname
    type = 'image/jpeg'
    uploader.upload(image,location,type)
  end

  def cache_update_request?
    @context.parameters.has_key?(:cache)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is nice overall, but here are my two cents :

- initializing instance variables before using them is not mandatory, so `initialize` as you implemented it is useless. A call to `@context` if it is not initialized will return `nil`.
- Since uninitialized instance variables return `nil`, you may have have problem when doing things like `@context.parameters[:cache]`. As such, i would advise to initialize them... in `initialize` :

  ```
  class Generator
    def initialize( params )
      @context = Context.new( params )
    end
  end
  ```

This also leaves you the latitude to inspect the params and throw an `ArgumentError` if some usefull params are not present.

- I think your object has mixed responsibilities. What does it represent ? It is not clear at first glance. Is it an uploader, an image ? It looks like a Service to me (the process is stateless), or maybe a "context" in DCI slang. Maybe your structure could more accurately represent this :

  ```
  module ImageGeneratorService

    def self.start( params )
      cache = params.delete( :cache )
      image = ImageFactory.create_from_params( params )
      CacheService.cache_image( image, cache ) if cache
      image
    end

  end
  ```

... ok, it's a bit too much, but i think you get the spirit. YMMV

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `initialize` should be doing what it's in `start`. But -1 for those terribly unidiomatic spaces around parentheses.

Comment: I used not to use parentheses at all... But then, there a are times you have to use them, and when you do it (when chaining ActiveRecord query methods, for instance) in my experience it is much more readable to add spaces, because arguments stand out. Then again, it's just a matter of taste... I usually adapt to whatever conventions my team use.

Answer (score 1):

Looks OK, except for a few small notes on style.

- Don't `return`, just let things fall off the end of methods:

  This...

  ```
  def start(params)
    @context = Context.new params
    image = create_image
    if cache_update_request?
      upload image
    end
    return image
  end
  ```

  Could be this:

  ```
  def start(params)
    @context = Context.new params
    image = create_image
    upload image if cache_update_request?
    image
  end
  ```
- Drop some of the temporary variables

  While I'm not generally a fan of excessively long one-liners, I think several of your multiline methods could be written using a fraction of the characters as one-liners:

  This...

  ```
  def create_image
    composer = Composer.new @context
    execution_context = ExecutionContext.new(@context, composer)
    execution_context.render
  end
  ```

  Could be this:

  ```
  def create_image
    ExecutionContext.new(@context, Composer.new @context).render
  end
  ```

  This...

  ```
  def upload(image)
    uploader = CompositorCommons::CacheUpdater.new
    filename = @context.parameters[:cache]
    location = 'dual/' + filname
    type = 'image/jpeg'
    uploader.upload(image,location,type)
  end
  ```

  Coule be this:

  ```
  def upload(image)
    uploader = CompositorCommons::CacheUpdater.new
    filename = @context.parameters[:cache]
    uploader.upload(image, "dual/#{filename}", "image/jpeg")
  end
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It also feels like unless you really want to expose the `create_image`, `upload`, and `cache_update_request?` in a public interface, you should encapsulate them and make them private.